# iTextSharp for reading PDF files is not working on Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, itext

I'm using iTextSharp.dll to read the contents of a PDF file. On a Windows server it is working correctly, but not on the Mono platform.

Mono error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I'm using this code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);

    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
    text.Append(currentText);
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using? Which specific line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, the problem was in path.

When I read text, I have problem with special characters (Slovak language {š, č, ť, ž ý, á, é, í, ...}). After read I have character "?", example =>  často => ?asto